# Invoking Executor shutdown in Weblogic Webservice

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, jakarta-ee, servlets

This is for a related thread  [Background Thread Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260246/background-thread-creation-in-weblogic-soap-webservice-using-executor-framework)

> On creating a static Fixed thread pool and doing an application
>   restart alone the Threads have started to hang and new threads are unable to process the requests.

Can someone help me know how to override the destroy function of Servlet in the Weblogic Webservice. 
This webservice has an entry in web.xml file and configured as servlet however, it does not implement HTTPServlet.

```
@WebService(serviceName = "ClientTestService", targetNamespace = "http://saurav.com/", endpointInterface = "com.saurav.ClientTest")
@WLHttpTransport(contextPath = "ClientTestService", serviceUri = "ClientTest", portName = "ClientTestPort")
public class ClientTestImpl implements ClientTest {//Actual Implementation here}
```

Is there a mechanism to shutdown the threads. As per the Java docs below contextDestroyed() cannot be used since the Instance of webservice (or servlet) would have been destroyed already.

> All servlets and filters will have been destroyed before any
>   ServletContextListeners are notified of context destruction.

Comment: look here for shutdownhook http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332832/graceful-shutdown-of-threads-and-executor

Comment: @awesome I am looking for shutdown in the web container.

Comment: How about using a servlet to initialize the thread pool and shutdown from the same.